# Developing Apps in Sharepoint

Tags: 2013, development, office-365, apps-development, office-365-develop-tool

I want to learn how to develop apps for SharePoint. I created a new developer site collection. When I try to install **NAPA Office Tool** I get the following message

> Sorry this app is not supported on your server.

I looked it up and the problem was that I don't have Office 365 in my server. I have license for office 2013 professional but, I am not sure it will work using it.

I need help with Office 365 configuration on Windows Server 2012 R2 and how to connect it to my SharePoint. I am not sure how to install it and where. If it could be done using office 2013 it would be great. 
I am sorry if this is off topic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Office 365 is a cloud offering, you don't install it anywhere local. Subscription options can be found [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/office365home/).

Comment: Just to add to your answer, here is a link where I have written how to start developing apps using NAPA and O365. http://www.sharepointnadeem.com/2013/12/sharepoint-2013-develop-sharepoint-2013.html

Comment: @NadeemYousuf That looks like a great guide, Thanks.